# SQL - Insert Into Aes_Encrypt Statement Error

Tags: mysql, sql, aes

MySQL is rejecting a certain part of my query. It's giving me the error 'A comma or closing bracket was expected (near ()' on line 18.

According to what I've found so far about the AES_ENCRYPT function, is that the statement itself is correct, but for some reason it keeps rejecting the query.

When I've used the query several months ago, it was working fine but for some reason now that I've been more actively working on the site itself, it stopped working for some reason and can't completely re-create the database.

The query:

```
    /* Adding data to the User entity */
INSERT
INTO
  Users(
    FirstName,
    LastName,
    EmailAddress,
    Password2,
    City,
    Street,
    PostalCode,
    PhoneNumber
  )
VALUES(
  'Test',
  'Administrator',
  'administrator@thisisatest.com',
  AES_ENCRYPT('123456', 'administrator'),
  '',
  '',
  '',
  ''
);
```

Comment: what is the datatype of `password2`?

Comment: can't see anything wrong with the code as-posted. Perhaps you've got a non-standard utf8 char masquerading as a `'` or `)` in there. try retyping the line from scratch.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. @vkp The datatype is VARCHAR with limit of 64 characters.

Comment: @Marc-B I've tried retyping the VALUES statement like you suggested, but it gives me the exact same error as before.

Comment: oh. and don't use varchar for aes data. encrypted data is basically binary garbage. it can/will contain byte sequences that LOOK like valid multi-byte character sequences in whatever character set you're using. that means your encrypted data will be either rejected for containing bad sequences, or corrupted on retrieval when translated to some OTHER charset. always use blob/varbinary for storing non-text data.

Comment: @marc-b Thank you for the suggestion. After reading it, you've convinced me to use the BLOB datatype for my passwords row.